# How to know if a phone is charging

Tags: android

I was wondering if there was a way to know whether or not the **phone** is **charging** or not, and possibly as an extra request, how to get the **battery percentage** level.

The data will be used inside an Android App.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2439619/115145 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/3291655/115145 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/33184981/115145 and so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Check if device is plugged in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283491/android-check-if-device-is-plugged-in)

Comment: See also offical tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

Comment: Thanks @MWiesner Fell like that's just like what I needed!